# MessageBox.Show to variable

Tags: c#, variables, foreach, messagebox

I have a for each loop as follows:

```
foreach (PCparts parts in items)
{
    MessageBox.Show(parts.PartName);
}
```

The loop returns 4 values in the following order: MOBO, GFX, CPU, and RAM

Now my question is, is there a way to store just one particular value into a variable or even just display it somewhere else like in a label or whatever? For example, store GFX into a variable that can be used later.

If you haven't noticed yet, I classify myself as a newbie so please don't be too harsh. I am trying to learn.

Comment: How is `PCParts` defined?

Comment: How do you know you want "GFX" to be stored, and not "CPU", "MOBO" or "RAM"?

Comment: Is `items` a `List<PCparts>` collection, or the results from a LINQ query?  The reason I ask is that if it's a list, you can access the individual objects in the list and assign the name to different variable or lists; if it's an `IEnumerable` query result, you'll lose that data once you finish enumerating.

Comment: it's a List<PCparts> collection.

Comment: Blorgbeard, I don't know, nor does it matter which one of the 4 is getting stored. I just want to know if it's possible and if it is, how would I go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have `items` defined as `List<PCParts>`, you can access the objects in the list anytime you want, so long as `items` is in scope.

So, for example, if you had a label (call it `lblName` for sake of the example), then you could do this:

```
lblName.Text = items[1].PartName;
```

Where `items[1]` is the second `PCParts` in the list (GFX).

Essentially, sine you have the list, you already have the data stored and can retrieve it.  You will need to know which item your looking for, if you're looking for a specific one.  For example, to build on your for each loop:

```
for each (PCpart part in items)
{

    if (part.PartName == "GFX")
    {
        lblName.Text = part.PartName;
    }
}
```

You could also use similar logic to store a selected value in a variable for further use:

```
string selectedPartName = items[1].PartName;
```

Without knowing more about what you are trying to do, it's hard to give a more definitive answer.

Comment: Perfect Tim. I knew you could access individual values from a list or an array by adding [#] but problem was that I was adding it in the declaration of the loop. Thank you again sir.

Answer (score 2):

In the interest of giving a different, yet equally useful answer to Tim, `PCParts` would be more amenable to this kind of operation if it were a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/xfhwa508.aspx) rather than a `List`. You'd be able to access the value corresponding to the `"GFX"` key with an expression like `items["GFX"]`.